# Chrome could not render tuckey urlrewrite output webpage

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter, render-html

We have recently upgraded one of our customers server's software including: Centos, Tomcat, JDK and MySQL. Now we find out that all pages that was returned from tuckey urlrewrite filter, could not be rendered on chrome or opera browser, but Firefox displays very well without any problem. All browsers except firefox displays html source instead of a rendered webpage. Meanwhile chrome and opera don't have any problem with pages that returned directly from application. This problem just exists on urlrewrite filters output. Also the html source that was displayed by chrome is the same as firefox html source of rendered webpage.

Comment: The question is too open to understand. Is there any page where we can see some output or images which shows the error?

Also, nothing was mentioned on the what versions are being used and to which versions are updated.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that apache tomcat HttpHeaderSecurityFilter prevents chrome importing web page dependencies such as js and css files when I am using tuckey urlrewrite. I disabled those filters temporarily to modify the filter soon.